# MSSQL query to retrieve DAX formulas from tabular model

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

First I would like to stress that Im quite new with the Analysis Services, so please forgive me if my question is not adequate.
I have received a task to display in Sharepoint list DAX formulas from existing tabular model and Im struggling to obtain this data using ms sql server.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Management Views are your friend. :-)

There are DMVs that you can query to return this type of information. The query engine for DMVs is the Data Mining parser. Although DMV query syntax is based on a SQL SELECT statement, it does not support the full syntax of a SELECT statement. Notably, JOIN, GROUP BY, LIKE, CAST, and CONVERT are not supported.

If you are just looking for calculated *measures*, you can use the following query and then filter out the rows where Expression is null

```
SELECT
[CATALOG_NAME] AS SSAS_Database_Name,
[CUBE_NAME] AS Cube_or_Perspective_Name,
[MEASUREGROUP_NAME] AS MeasureGroup_Name,
[MEASURE_NAME] AS Measure_Name,
[MEASURE_Caption] AS Measure_Caption,
[MEASURE_IS_VISIBLE] AS Dimension_Visible,
[MEASURE_AGGREGATOR] AS Measure_Aggregator,
[DEFAULT_FORMAT_STRING] AS [Format_String],
[EXPRESSION] AS Calculated_Measure_Expression
FROM
$SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES
ORDER BY
[MEASURE_NAME]
```

If you are looking for both calculated measures and calculated columns there is another DMV for that:

```
SELECT DATABASE_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, [TABLE], [OBJECT], [EXPRESSION] 
FROM $System.DISCOVER_CALC_DEPENDENCY
where OBJECT_TYPE = 'Measure' or OBJECT_TYPE = 'Calc_Column'
order by OBJECT_TYPE
```

The full list of DMVs for SSAS can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230820.aspx